# How can I abstract out a line of code that varies from item to item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I created a menu items below such that all of them are essentially the same except one line and that line is the line that holds the SVG file in html form as such:

```
// many of these
<span className="holder" onClick = {this.clickHandler.bind(this, 'Chat')}>
  // -> this line here -> <svg className='svg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/><path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H6l-2 2V4h16v12z"/></svg>
  <p className='p11'>Chat</p>
</span>
```

**Some new React element ( Menu Item )**

```
// create MenuItem with this render() function
render(){

    <span className="holder" onClick = {this.clickHandler.bind(this, 'Chat')}>
      // Put SVG element here using props or similar
      <p className='p11'>Chat</p>
    </span>

}
```

Is there a way to pass the SVG String in Props so that I can do something like this:

```
<MenuItem svg=svg_string>
```

I essentially want to pass and html element into a React Element ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably not pass in the svg as a string, and instead put it inside of the `MenuItem` component when I include it elsewhere:

When including the menu item:

```
render() {
    return (
        <MenuItem>
          <svg className='svg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/><path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H6l-2 2V4h16v12z"/></svg>
        </MenuItem>
     );
}
```

To do this, in your `MenuItem` you include `this.props.children` in the render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <span className="holder" onClick = {this.clickHandler.bind(this, 'Chat')}>
          {this.props.children}
          <p className='p11'>Chat</p>
        </span>
    );
}
```

Comment: I do like that form more. Thanks.  Do you develop React professionally or for fun?

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi - professionally, but that's sometimes fun :)

Comment: Good approach but I think MenuItem should the following props to make more digestible. `title`, `onClick` and `name`. I would remove the bind and point towards an arrow function.

Comment: @made - do I tie the CSS for the child element to `Menu` or `MenuItem` .  My guess would be the parent `Menu`

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi - i would do it in the parent, yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the SVG path programatically in code? 
If so it may make sense to put that logic in your MenuItem component.

If not (the svg path is static), I would save the SVG into a file, and then pass the file reference into the props.

I would need more information to answer your question.